# Group layers in layer list

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm new to ArcGIS API for Javscript V3, and trying to dynamically create group layers and add layers together in a existing layer list. I'm not sure how to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any sort of capability in 3.x to provide group layers. This is why ArcGIS Online web maps currently cannot support group layers. The [GroupLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GroupLayer.html) class was introduced in the 4.x API.

The only way to have group layers in 3.x is to use map services that are already configured with group layers.